# bash script to automatically login into website but the source code is called through iframe any idea?

Tags: bash

I am new to bash scripting,
i need to create a bash script which will automatically login into a website and at that website login page is called through the iframe so i need to know is there any conflict in bash script for iframe use in website page and if there is no conflict then please advise me how to create that script.

Comment: Please show what you have tried so far, StackOverflow is not a code writing service. You need to show at least some initial effort and point out a concrete problem you have encountered, and people will be gladly to help you then.